# Agile Practices: Code Review - Fail the review or raise an issue?

Tags: agile, code-reviews

At the end of a 2 week sprint and a task has a code review, in the review we discover a function that works, is readable, but it's quite long and has a few code smells. Easy refactor job.

Otherwise the task fits the definition of done.

We have two choices.

- Fail the code review, so that the ticket doesn't close in this sprint, and we take a little hit on morale, because we cannot pass off the ticket.
- The refactor is a small piece of work, and would get done in the next sprint (or even before it starts) as a tiny, half point story.

My question is: **are there any inherent problems or considerations with raising a ticket off of the back of a review, instead of failing it?**

The resources I can find and have read detail code reviews as 100% or nothing, usually, but I find that is usually not realistic.

Comment: So, if you can't fail the code review for that, what's the purpose of the review? Right now it seems that to you it's to see if something *works*, however, surely that's the job of a test or a tester, not a code review.

Comment: I think most of the answers miss an importat point in your question: *Otherwise the task fits the definition of done.* Are the issues you mention part of what your team considers a "not done" task? Or these issues are not considered in what a "done" task should be? If your definition of "done" includes "no code smells" then the task is simply not done.

Comment: @JoshPart The ambiguity shows up because the code review spotted a piece of work that needed doing, but strictly speaking was not because of the code change, it was just in the same area - the complexity of a given function - but I felt that specific scenario would be less valuable than the question at large.

Comment: @vlaz The purpose of a code review is to check that the change is up to standard, achieves the requirements and is maintainable.

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose so it sounds like the change wasn't up to standard and was possibly not (as easily) maintainable. Although your other comment seems to indicate that the change wasn't part of the request, in which case it shouldn't be part of the code review. If somebody writes a correct and up-to-standard code next to an existing ugly hack, then, feel free to, raise a ticket for fixing the ugly hack and pass the current code review.  If somebody writes a code that is correct but not up to standard (as your question indicates), then don't complete the code review until it's done correctly.

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose: Ah, so the code smell way _not created while working on the story under review_, but already existed? That's an important distinction - consider editing the question.

Comment: @vlaz you should make an answer from your comment

Comment: As a developer who's never really done agile, the amount of hand-wringing going on about this is not making me eager to go work for an agile shop. You have some technical debt that you can pay today or pay tomorrow. If you have to account for that in someone else's arbitrary model of the world (e.g. billable contract hours) then so be it, but here you're worried about how to account for it in an arbitrary model of the world that the team picked for itself (unless imposed from above, which is a red flag in itself). Is this buying you enough to make it worth the cost?

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose You should know better than to munge multiple issues into a single PR.  "I found it while reviewing a different change in the same file" is just as poor justification as "we need to treat our devs like they have the fragile morale of kindergarteners".

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> are there any inherent problems or considerations with raising a ticket off of the back of a review, instead of failing it?

Not inherently. For example, the implementation of the current change may have unearthed a problem which was already there, but wasn't known/apparent until now. Failing the ticket would be unfair as you'd fail it for something unrelated to the actually described task.

> in the review we discover a function

However, I surmise that the function here is something that was added by the current change. In this case, the ticket should be failed as the code did not pass the smell test.

Where would you draw the line, if not where you've already drawn it? You clearly don't think this code is sufficiently clean to stay in the codebase in its current form; so why would you then consider giving the ticket a pass?

> Fail the code review, so that the ticket doesn't close in this sprint, and we take a little hit on morale, because we cannot pass off the ticket.

It seems to me like you're indirectly arguing that you are trying to give this ticket a pass to benefit team morale, rather than benefit the quality of the codebase.

If that is the case, then you've got your priorities mixed. The standard of clean code should not be altered simply because it makes the team happier. The correctness and cleanliness of code does not hinge on the team's mood.

> The refactor is a small piece of work, and would get done in the next sprint (or even before it starts) as a tiny, half point story.

If the implementation of the original ticket caused the code smell, then it should be addressed in the original ticket. You should only be creating a new ticket if the code smell cannot be directly attributed to the original ticket (for example, a "straw that broke the camel's back" scenario).

> The resources I can find and have read detail code reviews as 100% or nothing, usually, but I find that is usually not realistic.

Pass/fail is inherently a **binary state**, which is inherently all or nothing.

What you're referring to here, I think, is more that you interpret code reviews as requiring *perfect* code or otherwise failing it, and that is not the case.

The code shouldn't be immaculate, it should simply comply with the reasonable standard of cleanliness that your team/company employs. Adherence to that standard is a binary choice: it adheres (pass) or it doesn't (fail).

Based on your description of the issue, it's clear that you don't think that this adheres to the expected code standard, and thus it should not be passed for ulterior reasons such as team morale.

> Otherwise the task fits the definition of done.

If "it gets the job done" were the best benchmark for code quality, then we wouldn't have had to invent the principle of clean code and good practice to begin with - the compiler and unit testing would already be our automated review process and you wouldn't need code reviews or style arguments.

Comment: "The correctness and cleanliness of code does not hinge on the team's mood." +1 for this alone, however the only caveat to this entire answer would be hitting a deadline. If failing this code review means a highly anticipated feature won't make it into the next release, you must balance code cleanliness with client needs. But remember incorrect code that meets the client's deadline today is a production issue tomorrow.

Comment: Great answer - firm but not rude. One tangential point may also be: how did we get to do code reviews so late in the sprint that an easy refactor couldn't be done without causing the whole sprint to fail?

Comment: @Daniel: The developer may be otherwise engaged, or it may be a planning issue. The time between finishing a task and finishing the sprint is usually minimal since (in an ideal world) people would be finishing their last task of the sprint around the  closing time of the sprint. You can't take an extended period to review/fix; or alternatively, maybe the developer is simply not present/available for the rest of the sprint.

Comment: +1 Programmers can feel good when they've written good code. Bypassing your quality control is not the answer to improving morale. An occasional rejection for minor issues is not likely to make morale suffer, anyway. If your morale is suffering because of regularly failing to pass quality control, the answer is to do something about failing QC all the time, not drop the standards.

Comment: @Flater Although your assumption was a little wrong (the problem was not introduced in the change, but the change was done inside the problem) I feel you addressed the question most succinctly, and your answer is valuable regardless of the 'why'.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Because I've seen the deadline argument being abused in many companies, I tend to only agree to passing a bad review _if and only if_ a task for its immediate refactoring is created and planned for the first post-release sprint. The added time cost adds a meaningful entry barrier to circumventing code quality.

Comment: @Flater: Absolutely agree. And you need to inform people the cost of making the deadline. "We can hit this deadline, but feature X will probably take a week longer, because we've got to clean this up now."

Answer (score 38):

> At the end of a 2 week sprint and a task has a code review [...] Easy refactor job.

Why does that pop up at the end of the sprint? A code review should happen *as soon as you think the code is done* (or even before). You should check your definition of done with each story you finish.

If you find yourself finishing stories so shortly before your demo/sprint review that you cannot fit it a "tiny" task, then you need to get better at estimating your work. Yes, that story did not get finished. Not because of a code review, but because you did not plan to incorporate changes from code review. That's like estimating "testing" to take zero time, because "if you programmed it correctly, it will just work, right?". That's not the way it works. Testing will find errors and code review will find things to change. If it wouldn't, it would be a big waste of time.

So to sum it up: yes, the DoD is binary. Pass or Fail. A code review is not binary, it should be more like an ongoing task. You cannot *fail*. It's a process and in the end it's done. But if you don't plan properly, you will not get to that "done" stage in time and are stuck in "not done" territory at sprint end. That's not good for morale, but you need to account for that in planning.

Comment: This is exactly the answer that came to my mind. If each story is being implemented with its own branch, then don't defer reviewing and merging the branches until the end of the sprint. Instead, create a pull request as soon as the branch is believed to be ready, and keep iterating on that branch until it is actually done, approved, and merged. If that process hasn't finished at the end of the sprint then the story isn't done.

Answer (score 21):

Simple: You review the *change*. You don't review the state of the program otherwise. If I fix a bug in a 3,000 line function, then you check that my changes fix the bug, and that's it. And if my change fixes the bug, you accept the change.

If you think the function is too long, then you put in a change request to make the function shorter, or split it up, *after* my change was accepted, and that change request can then be prioritised according to its importance. If the decision is made that the team has more important things to do, then it is handled later.

It would be ridiculous if you could decide development priorities during a code review, and rejecting my change for that reason would be an attempt to decide development priorities.

In summary, it is absolutely acceptable to accept a code change and immediately raise a ticket based on things you saw when reviewing the change. In some cases you will even do this if the change itself caused the issues: If it is more important to have the changes *now* than to fix the issues. For example if others were blocked, waiting for the change, then you want to unblock them while the code can be improved.

Comment: I think in this case the change *was* the overly long function--if you've introduced a 3000 line function that wasn't there previously (or was a 10 line function previously).

Comment: In principle this answer is exactly correct. In practice.....If all the developers believe in and practice good coding practices balanced against effort then you'd likely not run into this issue very often and then this answer is spot on. However....it seems that there's always that one or two developers who do everything quick and dirty in order to save 5 minutes now; whereas they ignore the hours to days or months they are adding to work that will be later. In those cases, this answer is just a slippery slope to having to start over and redesign the entire system.

Comment: +1, though I think you should rephrase the last paragraph to make it stand out that checking in code with issues should be an absolute exception. I mean, just that someone is blocked is _not_ enough excuse. Failing a single sprint doesn't look like enough excuse either, and certainly not an excuse that might be used repeatedly.

Comment: @user3067860 If you've turned a 10 line function into a 3000 line function - then clearly fail.  If you've turned a 3000 line function into 3010 - then probably pass.  But what if you've turned a 100 line function (usually a bit too big) into a 300 line function (*definitely* too big)?

Answer (score 9):

> Fail the code review, so that the ticket doesn't close in this sprint, and we take a little hit on morale, because we cannot pass off the ticket.

This seems to be the problem.
In theory you know what you should do, but it's close to deadline so you don't want to do what you know you should do.

The answer is simple: Do whatever you would do if you got the same code for code review on the first day of the sprint. If it would be acceptable then it should now. If it would not, it wouldn't now.

Comment: "Dear customer you can't have your feature for another 2-3 weeks because our code worked, but we didn't like how it looked", ...please don't go to our competitor ...or tell the CEO!

Comment: @RandomUs1r That's not what you would say (unless you want a job elsewhere). "Sorry, but we didn't finish this feature by the end of our 2 week sprint".

Comment: @gnasher729 "Dear developer, why wasn't the feature completed? Oh, cause of a code review process? Well I can fix that... we no longer have time for those."

Comment: @RandomUs1r customers shouldn't have that sort of information. It wasn't done because there wasn't enough time for it and that's that. Do customers dictate how code should be written? If you call an electrician to fix the wiring at your home, do you go "Just change the cables but don't bother checking if those are the correct cables"? Or do you tell your doctor "I'm sick - give me some pills but don't diagnose me first"? Code reviews should be an inherent part of the work, not something the customer dictates.

Comment: @RandomUs1r: _""Dear developer, why wasn't the feature completed?"_ - the answer should be "because we didn't have enough time to build it to an acceptable level of quality", _maybe_ followed by "We can give it to you if you're willing to compromise on quality".

Comment: @RandomUs1r so basically you want to sacrifice code quality now likely making it far harder to implement features later. A 2 day fix now could very well save you a 4 week fix later. So then it's "Dear customer, you can't have your feature for another 2-3 weeks because it takes that long to implement a minor feature now". Also is it the end of a sprint or is it a major deadline ? If it's a major deadline I could see merging now, writing a fix over the next 2 days and raising a PR right after deadline.

Comment: @xyious actually i'm satirically stating that we can't have nice things like code review processes at a lot of shops because people follow them to too rigid of a standard.

Comment: All I'm saying is that if your standards are different the first day and the last day of the sprint then you have no standard and your quality will inevitably go down the drain.

Answer (score 6):

A huge part of the process is deciding what *done* means and sticking to your guns.  It also means not over-committing and getting your peer reviews done in time to let testing ensure the work is also functionally complete.

When it comes to code review issues, there's a few ways you can handle it, and the right choice depends on a few factors.

- You can just **clean the code up yourself** and let the person know what you did.  Provides some mentoring opportunities, but this should be fairly simple stuff that can be done in a few minutes.
- You can **kick it back** with comments as to what is wrong.  If the error handling is done poorly, or the developer keeps repeating the same mistakes, this can be warranted.
- You can **create a ticket** and incur technical debt.  The ticket is there to make sure you pay it down later.  It might be that you are on a time crunch and in the process of reviewing the changes you see a bigger problem not directly related to the change.

Bottom line is that when you are done with work you need to be done with it.  If there are problems larger than what the developer worked on, raise the flag and move on.  But you shouldn't be in a position where there are hours before the end of the sprint and you are just now getting to peer review.  That smells like over-committing your resources, or procrastinating on the peer reviews.  (a process smell).

Answer (score 4):

There are no inherent problems with deprioritizing code review issues, but it sounds like the main issues you need to agree on, as a team, are:

1. What is the purpose of your code review?
2. How do results of the code review relate to the Definition of Done for a work item?
3. If code review does apply as a gating test, what issues are deemed 'blockers'?

This all comes down to what the team has agreed to as the definition of Done. If passing code review with Zero Issues is the definition of done for a work item, then you cannot close an item that has not met this requirement.

It's the same as if during unit testing a unit test failed. You would fix the bug, not ignore the unit test, if passing unit tests was a requirement for being Done.

If the team has not agreed to code reviews being a definition of Done, then your code reviews are not a gating acceptance test of the work item. They are a team activity that is part of your backlog process to look for additional work that might be needed. In that case, any issues you discover are unrelated to the requirements of the original work item and are new work items for the team to prioritize.

For example, it could be completely acceptable for a team to deprioritize fixing typos in some variable names as it does not impact the business functionality that has been delivered, even though the team really hates seeing the variable name "myObkect".

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to look at this problem in my opinion:

1. The academic way
2. The real world way

Academically speaking, most code review processes exist to fail the deploy of a PBI (product backlog item) when the code quality standard is not met.

However, nobody in the real world follows agile to the T as for one (of many reasons), different industries have different requirements. Thereby fixing the code now or taking on [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) (you'd create a new PBI most likely) should be decided on a per case basis. If it's going to compromise the sprint or a release or introduce an unreasonable amount of risk, business stakeholders should be involved in the decision.

Comment: *nobody in the real world follows agile to the T* – it won't be "agile" anymore if we have too strict rules, right?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I had an amusing conversation with a company I interviewed with one time. They claimed their process was not agile because it wasn't a textbook example of agile. Even though everything they did was in the spirit of agile. I pointed it out to them but was only met with (essentially) "No, we are not following an established agile procedure to the letter, even if we borrow the concepts heavily. Therefore, we are not agile". It was quite bizarre.

Comment: As other reviewers have pointed out, in this case there's potentially a lesson to be learned from the code's failure to truly pass the review. It looks to me as if the folks in this project really don't well understand that a) you need to leave time for review and fixes for each story, and b) the refactoring necessary to leave clean code behind is an essential part of the story. In that case, the best thing to do is to fail the story to make it clear that these things really are not optional.

Comment: @Curt I get that mine may be an unpopular view from a dev standpoint (I'm a dev too btw), but the business really should come first, they sign the paychecks and that deserves some respect.  As far as leaving time goes, I'll again challenge your understanding of the real world, and you need to realize that's not always possible and a lot of sprints run tight because devs need stuff to do at the end of the sprint too.  It's not like because the code's SOLID, a department can kick their feet up 1/10 days every 2 weeks and do nothing, that might be great in the short term, but isn't a viable long.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I work in the real world too, I take shortcuts all the time, and I _always_ put the business first, so I don't think I'm lacking in understanding here. But the OP's description was not "we normally always get this right and this was just a standard minor burp" or he wouldn't have been posting the question. As I explained in [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/380548/221703) it looks like a process problem, and you fix that by practising doing the process correctly before relaxing with it.

Comment: @RandomUs1r Also, your conception of a sprint is backwards: sprints can't run "tight" any more than a ruler can sometimes be "short" or "long"; how much you get done in a sprint is a measurement of your velocity, and to do that accurately you shouldn't every try to push harder than normal.

Comment: @Curt classic textbox agile, I've never seen it successfully practiced in the real world might be where our experiences differ.  For one you assume perfect efforting, something juniors devs don't do well, and while I agree pushing harder = burnout = empty chairs, I've never seen a velocity chart without noticeable fluctuation, thereby the case by case nature of my answer.  Lastly, I've never met a developer in Agile who hasn't failed a sprint... hmmm ;)

Comment: @RandomUs1r I've successfully practiced in the real world what you seem to be calling "textbook agile." If by "perfect efforting" you mean "perfect iteration estimation," no, that doesn't always happen, and isn't supposed to in textbook agile. The point is, pick the effort you want to put in and always use that amount of effort, no more, no less; then use what actually happened as feedback to improve your estimates. Since you're comparing estimated and actual velocity, the particular velocity number that comes out at any time isn't important and can indeed vary.

Answer (score 1):

The higher-voted answers here are very good; this one addresses the refactoring angle.

In most cases, the majority of work when refactoring is understanding the existing code; changing it after that is generally the smaller part of the work for one of two reasons:

1. If just making the code more clear and/or concise, the necessary changes are obvious. Often you gained your understanding of the code by trying out changes that seemed cleaner and seeing if they actually did work, or if they missed some subtlety in the more complex code.
2. You already have in mind a particular design or structure you need to make building a new feature easier. In that case, the work to develop that design was part of the story that generated the need for it; it's independent of you needing to do refactoring to get to that design.

Learning and understanding existing code is fair amount of work for a non-permanent benefit (a month from now someone's likely to have forgotten much about the code if they don't continue to read or work with it over that time), and so it doesn't make sense to do this except on areas of code that are causing you problems or that you're planning to change in the near future. In turn, since this is the main work of refactoring, you shouldn't do refactoring on code unless it's currently causing you problems or you are planning to change it in the near future.

But there's one exception to that: if someone currently has a good understanding of the code that will leak away over time, using that understanding to make the code more clear and more quickly understood later on can be a good investment. That's the situation someone who's just finished developing a story is in.

> The refactor is a small piece of work, and would get done in the next sprint (or even before it starts) as a tiny, half point story.

In this case that you're thinking of making a separate story for refactoring is a warning sign on several fronts:

1. You're not thinking of refactoring as part of coding but as a separate operation, which in turn makes it likely to get dropped under pressure.
2. You're developing code that will be more work to understand the next time someone needs to work with it, making stories take longer.
3. You may be wasting time and energy refactoring things from which you don't get much benefit. (If a change happens much later on, someone's still going to have to re-understand the code then, anyway; that's more efficiently combined with the refactoring job. If a change doesn't happen later on, the refactoring didn't serve any purpose at all, except perhaps an aesthetic one.)

So the answer here is to fail the item to make it clear that something in your process failed (in this case, that's the developer or team not allocating time for review and implementing changes that come out of review) and have the developer immediately continue work on the item.

When you go to estimate for the next iteration, re-estimate *the existing story* as whatever amount of work seems to be left to make it pass review and add it to your next iteration, but preserving the estimate from the previous iteration. When the story is completed at the end of the next iteration, set the historical total amount of work to the sum of the first and second estimates so you know how much estimated work was really put into it. This will help produce more accurate estimates of similar stories in the future at the current state of your process. (I.e., don't assume that your apparent under-estimate won't happen again; assume it will happen again until you have successfully completed similar stories while putting in less work.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised by the lack of response in the answers and comments to the notion of "failing" a code review, because that's not a concept I, personally, am familiar with. Nor would I be comfortable with that concept or anybody in my team using that terminology.

Your question explicitly calls on "agile practices," so let's revisit the agile manifesto (emphasis mine):

> We are uncovering better ways of developing
>   software by doing it and helping others do it.
>   Through this work we have come to value:
>
> - ***Individuals and interactions* over processes and tools**
> - *Working software* over comprehensive documentation
> - *Customer collaboration* over contract negotiation
> - *Responding to change* over following a plan
>
> That is, while there is value in the items on
>   the right, we value the items on the left more.

Speak to your team. Discuss the code in question. Assess the costs and the benefits and decide - as a cohesive group of experts - whether to refactor this code now, later, or never.

Start collaborating. Stop failing code reviews.

Comment: I'm all for collaboration. But what term would you use, if not "fail"? Even discussing, as a group, one person would say "this is not good enough, it needs refactoring" which means, simply, that it failed the quality check, right?

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose I've never used - or needed to use - the terminology of "failing" a code review. Someone reviews the code, a discussion around any potential points of improvement ensues, followed by a decision on whether to address those points. There's no "passing" or "failing" involved, just communication and progress. I'm not sure why there's a need for a rubber stamp.

Answer (score 0):

in the review we discover a function that works, is readable, but it's quite long and has a few code smells...

Are there any inherent problems or considerations with raising a ticket off of the back of a review, instead of failing it?

No problem whatsoever (in my teams opinion). I assume that the code meets the acceptance criteria stated in the ticket (i.e., it works). Create a backlog item to address the length, and any code smells, and prioritize it just like any other ticket. If it really is small, then just prioritize it high for the next sprint.

One of the sayings we have is "Choose progressive improvement over postponed perfection".

We have a very fluid process, and build a fairly good number of 'proof of concept' features (1 or 2 per sprint) that make it through dev and test but never make it past internal stakeholder review (hmm, can we do this instead?), alpha, or beta... some survive, some don't.

On the current project, I've lost track of how many times we've built a certain feature, gotten it into the hands of the stakeholders, and a sprint or two later, totally removed it because product direction has changed, or requirements caused a complete recast of how the feature should be implemented. Any remaining 'refinement' tasks for a deleted feature, or that don't fit the new requirements get deleted as well as part of backlog grooming.

Answer (score -2):

**Neither**. If it fails the code review then the task isn't done. But you can't fail code reviews on personal opinion. The code passes; move on to the next task.

It should be an easy call, and the fact that it isn't suggests that you don't have clear enough written down rules for code reviews.

1. "The function is quite long". Write down: Functions must be less than X lines long (I am *not* suggesting that rules about length of function are a good thing).
2. "There are some code smells". Write down: public functions must have unit tests for functionality and performance, both CPU and memory usage must be under limits x and y.

If you can't quantify the rules for passing a code review then you will get these case of what is basically 'code you don't like'.

Should you fail 'code you don't like'? I would say no. You will naturally start to pass/fail based on non-code aspects: Do you like the person? Do they argue strongly for their case or just do as they are told? Do they pass your code when they review you?

Also, you add an unquantifiable step to the estimation process. I estimate a task based on how I think it should be programmed, but then right at the end I have to change the coding style.

How long will that add? Will the same reviewer do the subsequent code review and agree with the first reviewer or will they find additional changes? What if I disagree with the change and put off doing it while I look for a second opinion or argue the case?

If you want tasks done quickly you need to make them as specific as possible. Adding a vague quality gate won't help your productivity.

Re: It's impossible to write down the rules!!

It's not really that hard. You really mean *"I can't express what I mean by 'good' code"*. Once you recognise that, you can see it's obviously a HR problem if you start saying someone's work isn't up to scratch, but you can't say why.

Write down the rules you can and have discussions over beer about what makes code 'good'.

Comment: Unless you argue that the ticket should pass by pure merit of there not being an explicit rule against it (which I disagree with but that's another discussion); this doesn't quite provide an answer to OP's current situation. A problem has surfaced which is clearly a problem - but let's say no explicit rule against it exists. The question still remains whether the current ticket should be failed or not regardless of whether a more explicit rule will be created for future encounters with similar problems.

Comment: @flater Yes that is what i am saying.

Comment: No, you're missing the point that "have a perfect and universally applicable standard with no ambiguities" is not a realistic prerequisite to doing code reviews. There will always be new types of issues that you hadn't yet accounted for, and thus you need to be able to make a decision in uncharted territory. Of course, you should then document that decision so it's no longer uncharted territory, but your answer rests on the assumption that you can somehow guarantee the absence of uncharted territory if only you draft the perfect rules before reviewing. You're putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: @flater if you think there is a missed rule having a meeting about adding it. Dont fail reviews because you believe the rules are wrong

Comment: And block the sprint while the meeting is planned/ongoing? Also, OP isn't considering failing the review because he thinks the _rules_ are wrong, he is considering failing the review because he thinks **the code does not comply with the rules**. You're the one who started talking about rewriting/appending the rules, not OP.

Comment: @flater, no pass the code because it meets the agreed apon standards. My point is that (I believe) the OP doesnt have clear standards to measure against.

Comment: Absolutes like "functions must be less than _x_ lines long" [aren't the answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/231427/20756), either.

Comment: @blrfl I generally hate argument from authority, but... famous ppl disagree with you  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method-for-you

Comment: Agreed with Blrfl. Functions (in general) shouldn't be more than 20 lines. But making it an absolute rule is a mistake. Specific circumstances *always* trump general rules: if you have a good reason for making your function more than 20 lines, then do that.

Comment: @matt you can always make a more complex rule if you like. or not have a rule at all. My point is _if_ you have a "functions must be short" rule. you have to say how short is short

Comment: You shouldn't need rules for code written to a legal specification... You can just have guidelines plus the fact that you are all presumably adults who are trying to accomplish the same end goal (working, readable, maintainable code). Having all the team members genuinely invested in the team and willing to work together is central to Scrum, so if you don't have that then maybe Scrum is not for your team anyway.

Comment: @Ewan  Amusingly, the accepted answer to that question emphasizes pragmatism over dogmatism.   Since we're doing appeal to authority, in 40 years of doing this, I have yet to hear anyone successfully make the dogmatic case case that _n+1_ lines is worse than _n_ lines for some value of _n_.  On the other hand, I've heard (and made) the argument that splitting a given implementation into parts improves testability or maintainability.  That's the argument to make.  The dogmatic route is great for getting noobs to adopt good habits, but it's unsuitable for seasoned professionals who can reason.

Comment: @blrfl true, but with a number like 100 or 200 you are setting the bar pretty high. But are you arguing for no length rule (I agree) or arguing for an unspecified length rule (i disagree)

Comment: @Ewan I'm arguing for no length rule.  Once you've moved all of the parts out of a function that need moving for good, non-LoC-related reasons, what's left will be exactly the right length.

Comment: @blrfl i agree. the point is though that the OP does have a length rule. all im saying is if you are going ti have one, you cant just say "looks too long to me" you have to define what the requirement is

Comment: @Ewan You can easily have a length which most functions should stay within, and still allow for functions to exceed that size for reasons of clarity or expediency.  The most obvious example is a "switch/case" statement in C-like languages.  This is universally acknowledged to be the clearest way to handle multiple conditions on the same  variable, but a large number of conditions (perhaps using an enumeration) can easily exceed a guideline size.  Most coding standards explicitly call this out as an always-allowed exception.  Remember these are *guidelines*, not hard rules.

Comment: @graham I think you are getting a little side tracked. The OP has a length of function rule. not me

Comment: @Ewan Sure.  My point was just that the OP has a length of function *guideline*, not a rule.  Wherever the threshold is set, it provides advice to help people spot hard-to-maintain code, but it's never an absolute rule.  If (as the OP says) it's actually perfectly readable, and the reviewers agree that it's perfectly readable, and there are no problems testing it appropriately, then the function is by definition the right size.  The review maybe gets a one-line note saying "Yes it's longer than advised, but we agree it's OK", and job done.    Refactoring after that point is gold-plating.

Comment: You equalize failing the code without a pre-approved rule to failing without a clear reason. That's simply a straw man. If a competent developers thinks that the code has issues and can name them, than the code has the named issues. If a set of trivial rules like the number of lines per function was enough, we would have used linters instead of peer review.

Comment: @frax, no I equate the lack of preapproved rule as a failure of the process and question whether that lack is in fact due to lack of a clear reason